# Error probability function

Tags: r, statistics, probability, probability-density

I have DNA amplicons with base mismatches which can arise during the PCR amplification process. My interest is, what is the probability that a sequence contains errors, given the error rate per base, number of mismatches and the number of bases in the amplicon.

I came across an article **[Cummings, S. M. et al (2010). Solutions for PCR, cloning and sequencing errors in population genetic analysis. Conservation Genetics, 11(3), 1095–1097. doi:10.1007/s10592-009-9864-6]** 
that proposes this formula to calculate the probability mass function in such cases.

[image]

I implemented the formula with R as shown here

```
pcr.prob <- function(k,N,eps){
  v = numeric(k)
  for(i in 1:k) {
    v[i] = choose(N,k-i) * (eps^(k-i)) * (1 - eps)^(N-(k-i))
    }
  1 - sum(v)
}
```

From the article, suggest we analysed an 800 bp amplicon using a PCR of 30 cycles with `1.85e10-5` misincorporations per base per cycle, and found `10` unique sequences that are each `3` bp different from their most similar sequence. The probability that a novel sequences was generated by three independent PCR errors equals `P = 0.0011`.

However when I use my implementation of the formula I get a different value.

```
pcr.prob(3,800,0.0000185)
[1] 5.323567e-07
```

What could I be doing wrong in my implementation? Am I misinterpreting something?

Thanks

Comment: I get 0.0011 with `eps ~ 0.00025`. What makes you sure their calculation (or formula) is correct?

Comment: how did you come to eps ~ 0.00025? am i not sure if their formula is correct …  i was searching for a solution and came across this. then i though of implementing the formula to check the validity of the example they gave (ps. am not a statistician).

Comment: My intent was not to criticize their work, just a starting point to start thinking what could go wrong. I found 0.00025 by trial and error. :) In my opinion, this is more statistics than programming question. I will flag it to be moved to crossvalidated.com.

Comment: The binomial distribution is in R already; just use the `dbinom` family of functions.  `dbinom(3, 800, 1.85e-5)` gives 5.303958e-07, and the difference from your implementation is likely due to rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they've got the right number (0.00113), but badly explained in their paper.

The calculation you want to be doing is:

```
pbinom(3, 800, 1-(1-1.85e-5)^30, lower=FALSE)
```

I.e. what's the probability of seeing less than three modifications in 800 independent bases, given 30 amplifications that each have a 1.85e-5 chance of going wrong.  I.e. you're calculating the probability it doesn't stay correct 30 times.

Somewhat statsy, may be worth a move…

Thinking about this more, you will start to see floating-point inaccuracies when working with very small probabilities here.  I.e. a `1-x` where `x` is a small number will start to go wrong when the absolute value of `x` is less than about 1e-10.  Working with log-probabilities is a good idea at this point, specifically the `log1p` function is a great help.  Using:

```
pbinom(3, 800, 1-exp(log1p(-1.85e-5)*30), lower=FALSE)
```

will continue to work even when the error incorporation rate is very low.